# Having issue with AR on iOS 7 and Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, vuforia

I developed a project with ninevehGL engine and vuforia sdk , every thing worked fine on xcode 4 , and iOS 6 , but today I compile my project and got two different strange errors :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/MK/Documents/Xcode project /CarShowcase/Qualcomm'
ld: library not found for -lQCAR
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

or

```
Lexical or preprocessor issue 'QCAR/Tool.h' file not found
```

I checked header path and everything is OK ! but is there any solution to fix these issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Lover,

Go to-> Target-> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries,

Here you will see, your missing libraries in red colour, indicating the libraries not found, just remove these. & add gain using "+" button -> Add Other, and then locate the libraries. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks , but there is no missing library or framework !